# How can acoustic absorbtion in air be used to model absorption in water?

Tags: acoustics

I am characterizing the sensitivity of a sound sensor that will eventually be used to receive acoustic signals under fresh water.  I'd like to get a good idea of how deep underwater I can go with a particular sensor setup.  However, going to the water to get my initial data would be prohibitively difficult for me.  As a result, I am testing the prototypes in air.

The transmitter will work at only a few discrete frequencies, which are still to be determined (based on which frequencies absorb less in the medium as well as which frequencies the transmitter can reliably produce).  So I won't be sending out arbitrary sound waves.

Presuming that I can figure out attenuation in air for my sensor, how could I use that data to help me to understand how well the sensor will work underwater?

For completeness, both the transmitter and the sensor will be underwater, so there is no problem with an interface between two media.  Also, I will be exploring other effects, such as alignment between the transmitter and receiver, but I believe these would not affect the attenuation rate I'm looking for.  I welcome a correction on that point.

Comment: I don't see how it would really help you.  The attenuation of water is quite different than air.  Any test you do in air would still require you to work out all the theoretical differences between air and water.  At that point, you're basically doing all the math to figure out what to expect in water, without having to use the initial experiment at all.  The only benefit I could see would be to determine the actual properties of your devices, if you didn't have good documentation already.

Comment: The impedance mismatch between your transducers and medium will be very different in the two media. This may be the dominant effect.

Comment: So to make sure I understand your points: JMac is saying that water and air are so different that I might as well just model water and not test in air, because the data from air is not helpful.  nasu is saying that the sensor and transmitter themselves will have different properties in water than in air, and so even if I could model the media appropriately it wouldn't help.  Is that right?